# Request from Chrome to server taking too long

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, google-chrome, networking

First, this is all ran locally on my machine. I have an AJAX request being made to a python script, where the script listens on a port for requests. I've tested this on safari, firefox and chrome. With safari and firefox the requests all make it to the port instantly and a response is sent back to the browser. However with chrome it takes 20s between the time that the request was made to the point where the python script sees the request. If i turn off "prefetch resources to load pages more quickly" in the chrome settings then the python script picks up the request instantly. What is going on?

python file:

```
import http.server
import socketserver

PORT = 80

class MyHandler(http.server.BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
  def do_GET(self):
    self.send_response(200)
    self.send_header("Content-Type", "text/plain")
    self.end_headers()
    self.wfile.write(b"My message\n")

httpd = socketserver.TCPServer(("", PORT), MyHandler)

print("serving at port", PORT)
httpd.serve_forever()
```

javascript file:

```
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.open("GET", "http://127.0.0.1:80", true);
xmlhttp.send();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
    var data = xmlhttp.responseText;
    console.log(data);
}
};
```

Comment: Add `self.wfile.close()` after last `self.wfile.write`

Comment: then the python script complains about BrokenPipeError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe and ValueError: I/O operation on closed file. Also while the browser still gets a response it again takes 18-20s, most of it being between the browser making the request and the python server script seeing the request on the port.

Comment: Cant check local, so can you try `self.finish()` instead of `close()` ?

Comment: same errors. I'm not sure if this is a chrome issue or my script issue.